# Template parse errors: 'mat-icon' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working with Angular CLI and angular material v.5.2.5
and trying to use

> mat-icon-button

but such an error produced by the console:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-icon' is not a known
> element...

if I use

> mat-raised-button

everything works fine
cannot figure out how to solve that

index.html

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todo</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

main.ts

```
 import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

app.module.ts

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The MatIconModule is missing from your imports.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule, // <-- here
],
```

Comment: 95% of all Material-related issues are resolved by importing the right modules.

Comment: And fortunately there are other answers specifying the package exportng the `MatIconModule`, thanks @freedev!

Comment: Well, in my case the problem was that I forgot to import the component that was using the mat-icon, and other stuff

Comment: This did NOT help. I got the error after updating to Angular 12.

Comment: @BluE same thing happen to me. I went from angular 8 to 12. the issue ended up being that the component that this error was coming from was not in the declarations

Comment: Did import MatIconTestingModule in my test, but that was appearently not enough...

Comment: It might help someone.I was getting other error too like <mat-divider> is not a known element,<mat-icon> is not a know element  and few others.After doing this MatIconModule all vanish

Answer (score 39):

## In Angular 9 or greater you should

```
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon'
```

and then

```
imports: [
    // other imports...
    MatIconModule, // <-- here
],
```

Comment: I'm doing the right imports, exports and into angular 9. But, still it is throwing same error. Any idea to resolve?

Comment: @meDeepakJain had you tried to remove `node_modules` and reinstall all the dependencies?

Comment: @meDeepakJain when doing lazy loading, i believe we also need to import the module in every sub-module we lazy load. i.e: inside `home.module.ts` we should also `import { MaterialModule } from '../app.material.module';`

Comment: @freedev Sadly deleting node_modules did not help either over here.

Answer (score 22):

I am using Angular 6. and I made a different file called material.module.ts where I keep all the mat Module dependencies. You can call this material.module.ts file in app.module.ts file It will work.When i added the 'MatIconModule' into my code It works for me.

here is my code.

material.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import {MatButtonModule,MatCheckboxModule,MatToolbarModule,MatInputModule,MatProgressSpinnerModule,MatCardModule,MatMenuModule, MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';


@NgModule({
  imports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,MatToolbarModule,MatInputModule,MatProgressSpinnerModule,MatCardModule,MatMenuModule,MatIconModule],
  exports: [MatButtonModule, MatCheckboxModule,MatToolbarModule,MatInputModule,MatProgressSpinnerModule,MatCardModule,MatMenuModule, MatIconModule]
})


export class MaterialModule{}
```

and app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: why do we need both import and imports at material.ts

Answer (score 7):

For me, The mat icon module was correctly imported but the components where the error was coming from were not in the app module declarations for some weird reasons.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
   TheFileWithMatIconTagComponent,
   ...
 ]
```

Comment: I was banging my head against desk trying to figure the issue and I didn't even realize that my component wasn't in app.module.  Fixed the issue and all was right in the world. Thanks for pointing this reminder out.

Comment: *ugh* Why was my component not in the module? Thanks, I would have never guessed to look for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material';// this must add to app module.ts

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatSliderModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatIconModule // this must add to app module.ts
  ],
```

Comment: `import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';`

Answer (score 5):

It also might happen that your `app.module.ts` or corresponding `.module.ts` file **doesn't compile**. If there are errors it will just throw out this error message instead of telling that there is an error in the module itself. Check out the related files for any issues with imports or code.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the modules and imported correctly still it does not work you can try this turn off the serve(`Ctrl+C`) and again start the server.

Answer (score -1):

run:

```
ng add @angular/material
```

and you'll be fine.