# Unable to implement material view in the angular 6 getting below error

Tags: javascript, android, angular, angular-ui-router

I have just created a page using angular 6 and i want to implement material view for the UI. While implementing i'm getting the below error.

I tried added the material.js lib but no luck

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>
> ```
>  'mat-icon' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'mat-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("eld>
>     <input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 'text'">
>     [ERROR ->]<mat-icon matSuffix (click)="hide = !hide">{{hide ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}}</mat-icon>
>   </"): ng:///AppModule/ApplicationComponent.html@4:4
> 'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<h1>Products List</h1>
> <div class="example-container">
>   [ERROR ->]<mat-form-field>
>     <input matInput placeholder="Enter your password" [type]="hide ? 'password' : 't"): ng:///AppModule/ApplicationComponent.html@2:2
>     at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
>     at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
>     at compiler.js:24971
>     at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
>     at compiler.js:24881
>     at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
>     at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template parse errors: 'mat-icon' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50190337/template-parse-errors-mat-icon-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: I have tried added it but still im getting error.   ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(8,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material/button'.
src/app/app.module.ts(10,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/material/icon'.                                                                   I have ran  npm install when i created the project.. i have all dependency in my project path

Comment: Can you share your all codes clearly?

Answer (score 0):

In angular 6 you don't have to add .js file for using angular material you just have to install it through npm. Try following the [angular material getting started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) it should work.